# Why do ReplaceAll and With give different results?

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra

I expected both results to be $0_3$:

```
P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
A = MatrixFunction[Sin, t*P] /. t -> 0
B = With[{t = 0}, MatrixFunction[Sin, t*P]]

(* {{-0.362821 - 1.25562 I, 0.288053 + 1.1563 I, 0.107869 + 0.0658492 I}, 
   {0.133223 - 1.20752 I, -0.220254 +  1.22158 I, 0.181178 - 0.148004 I}, 
   {-0.0991967 + 0.526917 I, -0.208297 - 0.517217 I, 0.583075 + 0.0340421 }} *)

(* {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}} *)
```

Following `J.M.` comments:

```
P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}, MachinePrecision -> 20] (* => A == B *)
P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}, MachinePrecision -> 10] (* => A == B *)
P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}, MachinePrecision -> $MachinePrecision] (* => A != B *)
a = $WorkingPrecision; P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}, MachinePrecision -> a] (* => A == B *)
```

Also, using `SetPrecision` `A` is zero:

```
P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]
A = MatrixFunction[Sin, t*SetPrecision[P, $MachinePrecision]] /. t -> 0
```

So it's not a misunderstanding of mine, but a peculiar behaviour of MMA.

Comment: Check this: `MatrixFunction[Sin, t*P][[1, 1]] // Expand` and try to figure out what happens in the other case.

Comment: It seems that I'm making a mistake of the kind "$(t\mapsto f(0))'$ instead of $f'(0)$" but I can't figure out where. Why isn't `MatrixFunction[Sin, t*P]` a function of $t$, and $B$ it's value in $0$?

Comment: What happens if you use a matrix that is not machine precision; e.g. `P = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];`?

Comment: @FredSimons This I understand, what I don't undertand is why it does not match.

Comment: @J.M. Both results are the same if I specify `WorkingPrecision -> ` to something different than `WorkingPrecision`. Even if I set `a=$MachinePrecision`, then I have the expected result with `WorkingPrecision -> a`. Not clear why...

Comment: Likely, something peculiar is happening in the machine-precision evaluation, if so. Another confirmatory test: generate the random matrix again, but without the `WorkingPrecision` setting, and compare what happens when you feed it the usual machine precision matrix and the result of `SetPrecision[P, 20]`.

Comment: @J.M. Then it's zero, even with `MatrixFunction[Sin, t*SetPrecision[P, $MachinePrecision]] /. t -> 0`.

Comment: It is a bug that has been fixed in the development version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BUG FIXED IN V11.1.0, CONFIRMED IN EARLIER VERSIONS**

This is really nothing to do with `With` and `ReplaceAll`.  (In the case of `With` the substitution `t=0` happens first, so the apparent bug is not triggered).

It looks as if Mathematica gives incorrect answers for

```
MatrixFunction[Sin, t * P]
```

in almost all cases where `P` is a machine precision square matrix of size 2 or larger, and `t` is unassigned.  This does *not* appear to be a precision issue.

For example, define notionally equivalent matrices

```
P = {{1, 2}, {4, 3}}/4;

Aa = MatrixFunction[Sin, t P];
An = MatrixFunction[Sin, t N[P]];
```

Compare

```
Aa /. t -> 0
An /. t -> 0
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)
(* {{0.421637, -0.210819}, {0.843274, -0.421637}} *)
```

Further, compare the notionally equivalent

```
MatrixFunction[Sin, N[P]]
Aa /. t -> 1.0
An /. t -> 1.0
(* {{0.151392, 0.398796}, {0.797592, 0.550188}} *)
(* {{0.151392, 0.398796}, {0.797592, 0.550188}} *)
(* {{1.08194, -0.0664758}, {0.265903, 0.816033 *)}}
```

This even occurs when `P` is real, symmetric, positive definite with integer coefficients.

*UPDATED*

This appears to be the result of Mathematica choosing an incorrect algorithm in the specific (and probably unusual) case where `MatrixFunction` is applied to the product of an unassigned variable and a machine precision matrix.  The results given appear to be incorrect for all values `t` and occur in cases where the matrix is well behaved (the Schur and Jordan decompositions computed in machine precision agree closely with their exact values).  Computing the results with any finite precision (not machine precision) does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: A possible workaround would have been to use `SchurDecomposition[]` first, apply `MatrixFunction[]` to the (quasi-)triangular factor, and apply the similarity transformation. Unfortunately, I've seen that `MatrixFunction[]` still screws up on the triangular factors if they are machine precision matrices. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Another workaround is to define functions: `Aa[t_] := MatrixFunction[Sin, t P]; An[t_] := MatrixFunction[Sin, t N[P]];` do not seem to have the same problems as using the replacement.

Comment: (Sorry for my late answer) Why do you say it  does not seem to be a precision issue? The fact that it works for exact matrices and fails for almost every inexact matrices would make me think the reverse.

Comment: @J.M. Is it really a bug, or is it an ineluctable consequence of inexact calculation?

Comment: @anderstood, can't tell, as I don't know the fine details of `MatrixFunction[]`, except that I know it's using Schur-Parlett in the inexact case and Jordan in the symbolic/exact case.